# sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'user@host'(using password: YES)"

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, heroku

I got the following error when trying to use my react app that linked to mysqldb using nodejs:

```
code: "ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR"
errno: 1045
fatal: true
sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'user@host' (using password: YES)"
sqlState: "28000"
```

the nodejs hosted at ***Heroku*** and ***Mysqldb*** in an other server.

the password and user are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by adding the server where my front-end part are in to the authorized hosts to connect to my second server where I have the back-end part.
this error will launch only when you are using different servers for one micro-service app that used a mysql database and that required user and password to access.

In my case I used Cpanel so I navigate into an area when you can add your server and I put the name of server as authorized and then it's solved.

Just look into your cpanel and read the menu and click on something like "add hosts" or "add servers" or "authorized hosts" or whatever you they call it on the version you have and you will find a list where you can add it .